Azure Function App deployment issue with multiple projects
I have an Azure Function App developed using .NET 8 containing Project A and Project B, each with some Azure functions. However, after deployment with CICD pipeline in the Azure portal, I cannot see functions from Project A in the Function App. I updated the functions.metadata file with both function lists, but to no avail. Any suggestions on how to fix this issue would be appreciated.
Azure Function App
│
├── Project A
│   ├── Function 1
│   ├── Function 2
│   └── Function 3
│
└── Project B
├── Function 4
└── Function 5
I could deploy all functions from each project in to the same function app

It's by design. You can't have 2 different projects,each containing some azure functions, deployed to a single azure function resource. You need to put them in one project or use 2 different azure function resources.
See this GitHub issue
Basically, each project resemble an azure function resource. If you deploy both of them to the same resource any previous deployment will be overwritten, not appended to.
